# Me abre el archivo en vez de descargarlo

Tags: html, html5

Estoy intentando descargar un archivo en HTML pero lo abre en vez de descargarlo.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 <html>
   <a  download="Go_To_PowerBI" href="../EjemploPaginaWeb/Down/DashBoard_PowerBI.bat"> Download </a>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si le quito la carpeta raíz, me arroja que no encuentra el archivo:

```
 <html>
    <a  download="Go_To_PowerBI" href="../Down/DashBoard_PowerBI.bat"> Download </a>
  </html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pueden ayudar por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De una respuesta a [Force a browser to save file as after clicking link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353425/force-a-browser-to-save-file-as-after-clicking-link):

Esto debe de funcionar sin problema alguno:

```
<a href="path/to/file" download>Click here to download</a>
```

En tu caso seria:

```
<a href="../EjemploPaginaWeb/Down/DashBoard_PowerBI.bat" download>Download</a>
```

Comment: Me sigue abriendo el archivo.

Comment: Esto sucede porque estas usando un archivo local, no estas usando un servidor, tu url es tipo File:/// no http://. Monta tu sitio en un servidor, o instala algo como laragon y monta tu sitio en ello y verás como funciona.

Comment: ya funciono. Gracias.